# I need to replace the hash key inside the array with values from a h`ash

Tags: ruby

I have an array like this

```
arr = [["ContactCreate", "Test1"], [nil, nil], ["ROW1", "one"], 
       ["ROW2", "four"], ["ROW3", "seven"], ["ROW4", "Ten"],
       ["ROW5", "thirteen"]]
```

and a hash like this

```
h = {"ROW1"=>["id=xxx", "TypeAndWait"], "ROW2"=>["id=xxx", "TypeAndWait"],
     "ROW3"=>["id=yyy", "Select"], "ROW4"=>["id=zzz", "SelectAndWait"],
     "ROW5"=>["id=aaa", "Check"]}
```

I want to replace first element of the each subarray with its hash value, provided it is a hash key. The resultant array should be as follows.

```
[["ContactCreate", "Test1"], [nil, nil], [["id=xxx", "TypeAndWait"], "one"],
 [["id=xxx", "TypeAndWait"], "four"], [["id=yyy", "Select"], "seven"],
 [["id=zzz", "SelectAndWait"], "Ten"], [["id=aaa", "Check"], "thirteen"]]
```

For example, `"ROW1"` in the third subarray should be replaced by `h["ROW1"]`.

Is there any easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (`arr` is your array, `h` is your hash)

```
arr.map do |x, y|
  [h[x] || x, y]
end
```

Comment: This assumes that no hash values equal `nil`. I expect that's a reasonable assumption here, but if not one could write `[h.key?(x) ? h[x] : x, y]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
h.default_proc = Proc.new { |h,k| k }
arr.map { |e1,e2| [h[e1], e2] }
```

This approach could also be used as follows.

```
arr = [["ContactCreate", "Test1", "Test2"], ["ROW1", nil], [1, "ROW2", "four"]]

arr.map { |a| a.map { |e| h[e] } }
  #=> [["ContactCreate", "Test1", "Test2"], [["id=xxx", "TypeAndWait"], nil],
  #    [1, ["id=xxx", "TypeAndWait"], "four"]]
```

The default proc merely causes `h[k]` to return `k` if `h` does not have a key `k`. See [Hash#default_proc=](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc-3D).

If one does not wish to modify `h` by attaching a default proc, one could attach the default proc to `h.dup` and use the dup in place of `h`.

Comment: Thank you very much. But it's not clear to me yet. I will take time to understand this and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: I edited to explain the function of the default proc.